# Limit the size of the post excerpt

Tags: excerpt

I am using this filter for Custom excerpts

```
<?php echo excerpt(90); ?>
```

http://bavotasan.com/2009/limiting-the-number-of-words-in-your-excerpt-or-content-in-wordpress/

but this filter not working in first featured post showing default 55 words

else it's working fine

```
<?php 
$count = 1;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if($count == 1) : ?>
<div id="featurd_post">
<div class="ftrd_image">
<?php woo_get_image('image',455,245,' '.$GLOBALS['align']); ?>   </div>
<div class="fix"></div>
<div class="ftrd_entry">
<h2 class="title">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php  the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="fetrd_entry">**<?php echo excerpt(90); ?>**</p>
<a href="#" title="" class="read_more">(<?php _e('&#2310;&#2327;&#2375; 
&#2346;&#2338;&#2375; ', 'shreshthbharat'); ?>)</a>
</div></div>     
<?php else : ?>

<div id="post">
<div class="post_image">
<?php woo_get_image('image',455,245,' '.$GLOBALS['align']); ?>   </div>
<div class="fix"></div>
<div class="post_entry">
<h2 class="title">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php  the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="fetrd_entry">**<?php echo excerpt(90); ?>**</p>
<a href="#" title="" class="read_more">(<?php _e('&#2310;&#2327;&#2375; 
&#2346;&#2338;&#2375; ', 'shreshthbharat'); ?>)</a>
</div></div>
```

please guide.

Comment: `excerpt()` is not a core WordPress function. Please include the function definition for `excerpt()` in your question.

Comment: please have a look http://bavotasan.com/2009/limiting-the-number-of-words-in-your-excerpt-or-content-in-wordpress/

Comment: Please post the code **in your question** - for posterity, if for no other reason.

Answer (score 3):

Try to go in a completely different way about that and this code to your functions.php

```
// Variable excerpt length.
function dynamic_excerpt($length) { // Variable excerpt length. Length is set in characters
global $post;
$text = $post->post_excerpt;
if ( '' == $text ) {
$text = get_the_content('');
$text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
$text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
}
$text = strip_shortcodes($text); // optional, recommended
$text = strip_tags($text); // use ' $text = strip_tags($text,'<p><a>'); ' if you want to keep some tags
$text = mb_substr($text,0,$length).' ...';
echo $text; // Use this is if you want a unformatted text block
//echo apply_filters('the_excerpt',$text); // Use this if you want to keep line breaks
}
```

Now when ever you want an excerpt in your theme use this line:

```
<?php dynamic_excerpt(125); ?>
```

125 is the length of you characters in this case...

Since this uses "mb_substr" **its also great** when using hebrew / arabic / chinese or any other langaues which has its characters being count differently.. so.. all around the best solution.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

After playing with your code, I don't see any bugs with the excerpt() function.

I am guessing your problem is with your post excerpt - are you sure you have set up the excerpt for your "featured" post to be longer than 90 characters? If you haven't set an excerpt, WordPress will auto-create one for you.

Comment: yeah i have set up the excerpt for "featured" post longer than 90 Words (Not characters)

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, this is what I'm using:
You can edit it the way you need it.

```
/** 
 * Sets the post excerpt length to number of words, except for some pages.
 *
 * @param int $length The current excerpt length.
 * @return int The new excerpt length in words.
--------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    function abc_excerpt_length($length) {
      // startpage
      if (is_home()) {
        return 5;
      }
      // search result page
      if (is_search()) {
        return 10;
      }
      // in the feed
      if (is_feed()) {
        return 20;
      }
      // on every other page
      return 40;
    }

    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'abc_excerpt_length');
```